# Error while retrieving saved user data in async storage - React-native

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, persistence

ERROR  Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:

1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
   See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.

**my code:**

```
const CustomSidebarMenu = (props) => {

  // const [token, setToken] = React.useState(null)
  const [userObj, setUserObject] = React.useState(null)

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const getData = async () => {
        try {
            const userInfo = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@u_info')
            if(userInfo !== null)
                await setUserObject(userInfo)
        } catch(e) {
        // error reading value
        }
        setLoaded(true)
    }

    getData()

    return () => null
},[])

return (
    <View style={stylesSidebar.sideMenuContainer}>
      <View style={stylesSidebar.profileHeader}>
        <View style={stylesSidebar.profileHeaderPicCircle}>
          <Text style={{fontSize: 25, color: '#307ecc'}}>
            {'School Pathram'.charAt(0)}
          </Text>
        </View>
        <Text style={stylesSidebar.profileHeaderText}>
        School Pathram
        </Text>
        <Text style={stylesSidebar.profileHeaderTextEmail}>
        {userObj.email}
        </Text>
      </View>
      <View style={stylesSidebar.profileHeaderLine} />
);
```

Can some one help me I am new to this react native tech.
What I am looking for with this code is, after login the user data is stored in the storage, and in the profile page and the navigation side bar, trying to retrieve it from the storage.
Please suggest the solution.

Thanks in advance.

**Edit 1**: I need to set the retrieved data while loading the sidebar/ the page.

**Edit 2**: I tried the below code also, but the same error:

```
const [userObj, setUserObject] = useState(null)

  useEffect(async()=>{
    let userData = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@u_info')
                    
    setUserObject(userData)
  },[])
```

Result: [image]

**EDIT 3:**
This works perfectly with normal Profile screen:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';


import {View, Text, Image, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';

const ProfileScreen = () => {

const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState('');
const [lastName, setLastName] = useState('');
const [email, setEmail] = useState('');

 useEffect(async()=>{
    const userData = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@u_info')
    let userInfo = JSON.parse(userData);               
    setEmail(userInfo.email)
    setFirstName(userInfo.firstName)
    setLastName(userInfo.lastName)
  },[])


  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.header}>
          <View style={styles.headerContent}>
              <Image style={styles.avatar}
                source={{uri: 'https://bootdey.com/img/Content/avatar/avatar6.png'}}/>

              <Text style={styles.name}>{firstName} </Text>
              <Text style={styles.userInfo}>{email}</Text>
              {/* <Text style={styles.userInfo}>Florida </Text> */}
          </View>
        </View>
...
```

Looks like some specific issue to the navigation sidebar.

Comment: Other than React state updates not being awaitable (they aren't `async`) and the weird `useEffect` cleanup function that just returns `null` I don't see any overt React hook issues. Are you sure *this* code is causing error?

Comment: @DrewReese Thanks for the reply, so normally, how did you write it for getting the async data while loading the navigation sidebar/page?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your question. What navigation sidebar/page are you referring to? Are you asking how to fetch your data asynchronously? You already do that. I'm just saying the `setUserObject(userInfo)` can't be awaited since `setUserObject` isn't an `async` function nor does it return a Promise.

Comment: @DrewReese ok, can you check my edit 2 in the question, will get more details about the issue I am facing.

Comment: React hook callbacks are also to be completely synchronous. `useEffect(async () => ...` won't work correctly. To be clear, `await setUserObject(userInfo)` or `return () => null` won't throw an error, they are just meaningless. I don't see any issue with breaking rules of hooks with your code so that is why I asked if you were sure this code was the problem.

Comment: Debugger shows `Render Error: Invalid hook call`, do we have any other option to find out the root cause?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232958/discussion-between-drew-reese-and-azeez).